Why is a 'Clock' Used in Computers?
To clarify, this is not a formal academic field of study for me. At around the timestamp of 11:10 in this video (https://youtu.be/I0-izyq6q5s?si=xQ6Ec2RvZuJm67tl), I find myself wondering why an additional 4-bit register, 'C', wasn't included to connect to the output of the algorithmic unit. This way, the output from register 'C' could then be used in the final calculation output, without affecting the calculation of the preceding 'ALU'.
Side note: I am not familiar with all the jargon in this field, so I apologise if I use some unconventional terms, though this video should provide sufficient context.
I understand that adding such a register could require more circuitry and thus, natural resources, potentially introducing some delay (from input to output). However, it seems that this delay would be minimal compared to the delay introduced by the oscillating clock. Furthermore, intuitively it seems that the clock would demand more power, thus, generating more heat, because the time the input is on for is increased. Yes, there would probably also be heat introduced by adding more circuitry, since I assume electricity doesn't flow through circuitry without some of it escaping, causing more of the battery's capacity to be used, but this would be negligible due to how quickly it would move comparatively.
This is kind of speculative on my part, as I don't fully grasp what humans understand about how computers work yet. This is because I'm only on part 2 of the series and I find that the presenter rushes through the fundamentals and makes the process overly (exclusively) abstract for the sake of simplification. The later would be okay if he demonstrated how these complex circuits connect to ground and power, how they actually look like and explained the workings of batteries, circuits and breadboards by simply disassembling them.
Edit: I found two videos that address what the fist does not (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WReFkfrUIk & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vRAACeebjI).
I say this because observing phenomena or the universe directly is why learning is possible, it is the purest form of learning. It helps us understand the foundations of theories, decode jargon and innovate by identifying flaws in existing theories. Of course theories can inspire practice, but theories can't exist without it in the first place.
